# AIR3.3+ sharedObject location on Windows 7+8

Tags: air, local-shared-object

read this

[sharedObject location

my LSO's should be found at

```
%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\
```

But in Windows 8 I only see a #SharedObjects folder here

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\
```

And its NOT the location of my shared objects!

I also understand that as of AIR3.3 Adobe changed the location of LSO's to make AIR for mobile compatible with iOS, but not sure if and how this impacts AIR for desktop on Windows.  So can anyone solve the mystery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found it for Windows8

```
\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\client\Local Store\#SharedObjects\
```